# How am I able to speed up the sliding window in Matlab for an operational object recognition?

Tags: python, matlab, matlab-cvst, object-recognition, sliding-window

I'm working on a high resolution data set for extracting desired image objects. To do this, I have applied HOG + SVM. Although the results I get are very promising and operationally accepted, the speed of this task is annoying! For each image, which is of size 2800 * 1400, the algorithm takes 4 minutes to be done, which is far from the time I need. Most of this time is taken for performing sliding window. I need this recognition procedure to be done within only 10 seconds. Since I make the use of Matlab, it seems that reaching 10 seconds is impossible and I have to think of C++. However, I've never worked with C++ and haven't enough time to learn it for this task.

I would be grateful to know that is there any ways to speed up the sliding window  in Matlab or Python to perform the recognition in under 1 minute?

Comment: It may be worth posting the code that you have on the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site for suggestions on optimization.

Comment: Not only will you need to use a language like C++ to improve efficiency, but you'll probably need to use CUDA to offload a majority of the computational overhead onto GPUs. I believe there are CUDA extensions/libraries for Python as well. Doing it in Matlab with only the use of a CPU will not get you even close to under a minute, let alone under 10 seconds.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you for your helpful comments. @Scott, if there exists CUDA modules for Python, is it possible to get the goal without employing C++?

Comment: Depending on the performance of the GPUs available to CUDA and the efficiency of your algorithms, certainly.

Comment: If you have the parallel computing toolbox, you also have CUDA support in Matlab.

Comment: @Jonas, thank you. Yes, I have used  parallel computing toolbox and also I have vectorized the scripts as much as possible; however, I'm not seeing any significant improvement in the speed.

Comment: @Federico  - the time spent in the body of the loop has to be sufficiently large for you to be able to see speed improvements when you replace `for` with `parfor`. Also, I assume you did try CUDA, then?

Comment: @Jonas, thank you for the reply. Yes, I use `parfor`, but it is also not an effective helper for my case.

Comment: @Federico: you may want to look into modifying your code, then. If you don't need to process individual frames sequentially, you can e.g. run `parfor iFrame=1:nFrames, %spend 4 minutes on a frame;end`, which brings processing to under 10s/frame if you run on 25 nodes.

Comment: @Jonas, thank you for your great suggestion. I'll try it and report the results.

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be HOG-SVM?

If not, then you can use the `trainCascadeObjectDetector` function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox. It trains a boosted cascade classifier, and it gives you a choice of HOG, LBP, and Haar features. Then you can use `vision.CascadeObjectDetector`, which implements the sliding windows internally using native code, making it much faster.

See [matlab documentation on training a cascade object detector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-a-cascade-object-detector.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I have already tested that function, but I got poor accuracy. On the other hand, when I apply SVM and HOG together, the result is the one I need and very accurate. I barely see false-classified objects when using this combination.

Comment: Interesting...  What kind of objects are you trying to detect?

Comment: Thank you for the response. My objects are traffic signs.